# I've created a background image for our website, but it is taking over the content

Tags: css, image, background, squarespace

I'm putting the finishing touches on a website for a friend. They would like to have cycling set of background images show up on their 'featured' page. I've tested that - NO PROBLEM. What's happening though is that the background image is taking over the content on the rest of the page.

I'm using Squarespace. This is the HTML that I've got so far:

```html
<div id="background-wrap"></div>
<div class="with-bg-size" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:900; width:100%; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden; margin:auto;"></div>
```

And the CSS looks lke this:

```css
body {height:100%; overflow-y:hidden;}

.with-bg-size
{
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10022474/events.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Now, that background image that I've placed takes over the rest of the content including the nav, so I'm stuck. Is there anything that I Can do?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without more knowledge of the HTML around this example, but first thing I would do is move the `div.with-bg-size` to the beginning of the HTML structure and remove the `z-index` style from it.